# JS: XMLHtttpRequest sending data not working

Tags: javascript, http

I´m trying to post some xml to an api with an http post. This is my code:

```
var urlGet = "http://192.168.156.38/data/static.xml"
var urlPost = "http://192.168.156.38/data/changes.xml"
var push = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Devices><Device><ID>EZR0116AF</ID><HEATAREA nr="4"><T_TARGET>17.0</T_TARGET></HEATAREA></Device></Devices>'

function httpGetAsync() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", urlGet, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}

function httpPostAsync() {
    console.log(push)
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", urlPost, true);
    xmlHttp.send(push); 
}
```

The get function works but not the request function. In my console all I get is this: index.html:34 GET http://192.168.156.38/data/changes.xml 0 ()

Im pretty sure my xml is correct. This is an example from the api description:

[image]

Any Idea what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: You can't send data with `GET`, only with `POST`.

Comment: You need to use `xmlHttp.open("POST", urlPost, true);` to post data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the method in your httpPostAsync function is "GET" when it should be "POST". The send function is sending data when you've specified a GET method, so maybe it is failing here.

Comment: Thank you! I am new about XMLHttpRequest and didn't new about that